# Python Flask - Profit/Flip calculation from API values

Tags: javascript, python, html, api, jinja2

I recently started working on a project for a Minecraft server named "Hypixel". They record actions that the community can access through an API. And particularly they have an NPC named "Bazaar" where you can make money from selling items etc, wont go into detail.

I am trying to make a "flipper" to my website, where it will display all the products, what user should buy/sell the product for, how much they should buy and then how much they will make depending on what value they have put into an input field above the table.

I made a flow chart for myself to try to figure this out, sadly no luck at all! You can see it below, might help you out to figure out this problem with me! :) OBS: Realized after post that bottom text of flowchart is a bit incorrect, "y" should be the margin for each product! (buyPrice - sellPrice = margin)

[image: FLOWCHART HERE]

Here is my current HTML (Jinja), meaning to be a table with values (so far I have only been able to get buy/sell price and product name from the API, on a different HTML file though.)

```
<table
    id="myTable"
    class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm table-dark"
    cellspacing="0"
  >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th aria-label="Product Name" data-balloon-pos="up">Product</th>
        <th aria-label="How much you will earn" data-balloon-pos="up">
          Profit
        </th>
        <th aria-label="How many you should buy" data-balloon-pos="up">
          Amount
        </th>
        <th aria-label="How much you should buy for" data-balloon-pos="up">
          Buy For
        </th>
        <th aria-label="How much you should sell for" data-balloon-pos="up">
          Sell For
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
```

I use this code in python to get product name, sell and buy price:

```
@app.route('/bflipper')
def bFlipper():
    f = requests.get(
        'https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=[key supposed to be secret, can share if needed, can easily change the code later :)]').json()

    products = [
        {
            "id": product["product_id"],
            "sell_price": product["sell_summary"][:1],
            "buy_price": product["buy_summary"][:1],
        }
        for product in f["products"].values()
    ]
    return render_template('flipper.html', products=products)
```

I am guessing I might need to have a bunch of javascript, which I am not that good in (studying it at the moment). And therefore searching for help over here!

Example of how the API looks (total of about 190+ products):
https://pastebin.com/EHTcebjw

Interesting parts are "product_id", "pricePerUnit" in sell/buy_summary.

Comment: What does get call return you , could you please share that?

Comment: This is what it returns on my second "Bazaar" page, where it only displays each products current price: https://pastebin.com/j0GHtKMS

Comment: I meant this : f = requests.get(
        'https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=[key supposed to be secret, can share if needed, can easily change the code later :)]').json() . So that I can help in making the js array object

Comment: Doing that in python lets me access the "id" "sell_price" and "buy_price" by doing {{ product.id }}, and for "buy/sell" price I had to make one more for loop as I needed to go one more "indent" into the API. In the code you can also see that I have "buy/sell Volume", which doesn't show in the python code up there. Reason being I have a second "app.route" for that, here is that app.route: https://pastebin.com/BmD1KpU9

Comment: yes, here it is: https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=73ac0a44-4c41-4933-a9ee-b4095be2b6d2 @HarmandeepSinghKalsi

Comment: Ok , I saw the response . Now you are facing issue in html rendering or js object formation?

Comment: I mainly don't really know how I should attack this. I need to somehow either get all the data from python sent to a JavaScript file, then do all code/calculations in my javascript file. Or I somehow need to do it in my HTML file, as you see at the bottom of the flow chart. That's what I need the code "to do".

Comment: so I need to grab the API sell/buy price (which I am currently storing in sell/buy.pricePerUnit, getting that value by doing a for loop saying "for buy in product.buy_price".) Code here: https://pastebin.com/bKzaqGUU | then I just need the buy price to add it self until it reaches the user input (for example 100k, and we have product priced at 10k, it will do 10k + 10k until it reaches 100k), then display "10" on "amount"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214539/discussion-between-simon-sjoo-and-harmandeep-singh-kalsi).